# Where can I see deactivated APKs in NEW Android console?

Tags: android, google-play

In the old Android console, deactivated APKs could be seen by switching to advanced mode.

[image]

In the new console, in the APK tab, I cannot find inactive APKs.

[image]

Any ideas???

**EDIT**

I already uploaded 2 APK files but none of them are visible in new console. You can see them in the old console view on the first image.

Comment: why don't you try to switch old Theme to which you can switch by clicking the link existing beside logout

Comment: @Nagaraj436 I can, but what about the future :). I would still need to find this in the future. Or it's not available in preview version?

Comment: It says "Upload your first APK", have you had uploaded any? There's no appication.

Comment: @nOiAd Please do not downvote in rush. **Of course I uploaded 2 APKs**. You can SEE them on the first image. Please cancel your downvote.

Comment: none of the app is activated or published.

Comment: my vote is locked unless this question is edited.

Comment: Yes, there is only 1 app in this account and it hasn't been either published or any APK activated.

Comment: You have to actually publish it once or gotta activate, I guess that's the problem with the new design.

Comment: In your screenshots above it says ``Active None`` and then ``previous Active none`` underneath. Doesn't look as if you've published an APK

Comment: @Boardy It seems that in new design, you can view older APKs only. And only after you published the app. It's not bad approach, but why **no one warned us about this change**?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Google made some changes in the way it handles APKs. Namely, you will not be able to view uploaded APKs **before you publish the app for the first time**.

I am reading all their messages about new console, and I have never read about this change.

So a solution is to **first** publish the app and **only then** you will be able to see all APKs and handle them accordingly.